# Unable to add initializer through the extension to a struct in Swift

Tags: swift, struct, initializer

I was trying to add convenience initializer with "centre" and "size" as parameters to the extension of Struct Rect but it is displaying error demanding for the intializer with "origin" and "size" as it's parameter. 
Error displayed in RunSwift compiler:

```
/var/folders/_x/3ll0j9g13tqfr6lj42jh8qjc0000gn/T/9799.swift:19:17: error: incorrect argument label in call (have 'centre:size:', expected 'origin:size:')
let cRect = Rect(centre: Point(x: 2.5, y: 2.5), size: Size(width: 5.0, height: 5.0))
                ^~~~~~~
                 origin
```

Here is the code:

```
    struct Point {
    var x = 0.0
    var y = 0.0
}
struct Size {
    var width = 0.0
    var height = 0.0
}
struct Rect {
    var origin = Point()
    var size = Size()
    // var centre : Point {
    //     let x = origin.x + (size.width/2)
    //     let y = origin.y + (size.height/2)
    //     return Point(x: x,y: y)
    // }
}

let cRect = Rect(centre: Point(x: 2.5, y: 2.5), size: Size(width: 5.0, height: 
5.0))
print("cRect origin is = \(cRect.origin)")
extension Rect {
    init(centre: Point, size: Size){
        let originX = centre.x - (size.width)/2
        let originY = centre.y - (size.height)/2
        self.init(origin: Point(x: originX, y: originY), size : size)
    }
}
```

Kindly help. I am stuck.

Comment: You just have to put the extension definition before its use.

Comment: In swift, from where should i start tracing the program? as there is no main in this.

Comment: It depends the environment, lldb (Swift RELP, Playground) or swiftc (iOS, macOS, etc.). The first one will perform in a sequential order while with swiftc you will have a linker.

Comment: Okay thanks! That was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Just move the extension part before your code where you are calling the init method (I assume you're using a Playground)

```
extension Rect {
  init(centre: Point, size: Size){
    let originX = centre.x - (size.width)/2
    let originY = centre.y - (size.height)/2
    self.init(origin: Point(x: originX, y: originY), size : size)
  }
}

let cRect = Rect(centre: Point(x: 2.5, y: 2.5), size: Size(width: 5.0, height: 5.0))
print("cRect origin is = \(cRect.origin)")
```